# How to delete a row in NSTableView (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstableview

I have been able to add strings/data to a table from secondViewController to firstViewController but now I want users to be able to delete rows as well. 
How will I be able to delete the row?

Update: So here is some more detail:
This is the code that I am using to create table in 1stVC.

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return arrayData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    return arrayData[row]
}
```

I have set an array as well that is getting the data from 2ndVC through a delegate. The values from 2ndVC are stored in a variable called "data" in the 1stVC and then added to an array like so:

```
arrayData.append(data!)
```

Now I want to put a delete button, that can remove the rows/inserted data.

Thanks!

Comment: this question needs more detail:  1) delete rows from the first or second view controller?  2) can you show code how the rows were added in the first view controller and sent over to the second view controller (e.g. was it done via a segue or something else?)

Comment: Hey! So I just updated the post.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is to remove the `object` from the data source array and then call `removeRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:` on the table view

```
if let index = arrayData.index(of: object) {
    arrayData.remove(at: index)
    let indexSet = IndexSet(integer:index)
    tableView.removeRows(at:indexSet, withAnimation:.effectFade)
}
```